# Change active Spring Profile while "git push"

Tags: java, spring-boot

[image]

[image]

Currently I have to manually update the value of **spring.profiles.active**, how can I change the value while I execute "git push" ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: While I am sure this can be done via some git hook script I don't think it is required. You can have default value of `spring.profiles.active` as dev. Then simply provide 'prod' value via jvm argument or system property wherever it is running in production.

Comment: Do those application-*.yml files have connection strings, ID/passwords in them?

Comment: update: the jvm argument approach worked, thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot can read properties from different external sources. These sources are considered in a defined order.

If *application.properties* contains `spring.profiles.active=prod` you could override this value e.g. by defining a system property `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` when running the application. In this you don't need to touch the *application.properties* file.

See also the [Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config).